# How do you read an xCBL document from a VB.Net application or web service?

Tags: xml, vb.net, web-services, xml-parsing

A supplier of ours tells us that they can submit xCBL messages to us via a web service (which we would host, presumably at the edge of our network).

They're unable to give us any help setting up such a web service, provide any samples or documentation because they're bogged down with other projects.

Keen to make a head start, I've acquired a sample OrderResponse message from them, so that I could interpret it and figure out how I could integrate such messages into our systems to automate some communication processes between us.

Unfortunately, I'm having a hard time finding any getting started guides, tutorials or YouTube videos on the subject.  Perhaps I haven't Googled the right terms?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the [xCBL Messaging Specifications](http://www.xcbl.org/xcbl40/xcbl40.shtml)? Once you have something to parse the XML structure and extract the data you need, the rest is just a matter of a simple web service that will accept file uploads from (presumably) authenticated sources.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken you have to validate the message as well using the appropriate schema's Again the [xcbl website](http://www.cxbl.org) is probably your best starting point.

Comment: Thanks for the hints guys.  I've managed to download the XSD schema files, create classes from them using xsd.exe and successfully deserialize an XML message.  I still haven't managed to find one decent walk through detailing the process - I just muddled through using scraps of info I found through Google searches.

Comment: May I suggest writing one, then? If you find insufficient documentation available, solve that problem for the next person who comes looking for it.